# How to completeley disable presolve in scip

Tags: scip

As the titles says, how can you completely disable presolve in scip.
I need this because otherwise SCIPgetDualSolVal and SCIPgetVarRedcost don't return be the (correct) values.

I tried the following parameters:

```
lp/presolving = false
concurrent/presolvebefore = false
presolving/maxrounds = 0
```

Especially the last one mostly helps but not completely.

Following model for example:

```
Minimize
 Obj: +1 COLONE +3 COLTWO +6.24 COLTHREE +0.1 COLFOUR
Subject to
 THISROW: +78.26 COLTWO +2.9 COLFOUR >= +92.3
 THATROW: +0.24 COLONE +11.31 COLTHREE <= +14.8
 LASTROW: -1 COLTHREE <= -0.1
Bounds
 0.6 <= COLONE
 18 <= COLFOUR <= 31.5
End
```

Is still translated to:

```
Minimize
 Obj: +1 t_COLONE +3 t_COLTWO +6.24 t_COLTHREE +0.1 t_COLFOUR
Subject to
 THISROW: +78.26 t_COLTWO +2.9 t_COLFOUR >= +92.3
Bounds
 0.6 <= t_COLONE <= 0.6
 0.0121390237669308 <= t_COLTWO <= 100000.45
 0.1 <= t_COLTHREE <= 0.1
 18 <= t_COLFOUR <= 31.5
End
```

Is there a way completely disable presolve in scip?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable all presolving by calling (from the interactive shell) `set presolving emphasis off`.
If you want to save this to a settings file you can afterwards call `set diffsave <filename>`

Edit: I checked the small problem example that you gave and after presolving the problem did not get changed, but rather during the solution process. If you do not want that you also have do disable propagation with

```
propagating/maxrounds = 0
propagating/maxroundsroot = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer.
When I enter this it shows:

```
presolving/milp/maxrounds = 0
presolving/trivial/maxrounds = 0
presolving/inttobinary/maxrounds = 0
presolving/gateextraction/maxrounds = 0
presolving/dualcomp/maxrounds = 0
presolving/domcol/maxrounds = 0
presolving/implics/maxrounds = 0
presolving/sparsify/maxrounds = 0
presolving/dualsparsify/maxrounds = 0
propagating/dualfix/maxprerounds = 0
propagating/genvbounds/maxprerounds = 0
propagating/obbt/maxprerounds = 0
propagating/nlobbt/maxprerounds = 0
propagating/probing/maxprerounds = 0
propagating/pseudoobj/maxprerounds = 0
propagating/redcost/maxprerounds = 0
propagating/rootredcost/maxprerounds = 0
propagating/symmetry/maxprerounds = 0
propagating/vbounds/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/cardinality/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/SOS1/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/SOS2/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/varbound/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/knapsack/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/setppc/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/linking/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/or/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/and/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/xor/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/conjunction/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/disjunction/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/linear/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/orbisack/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/orbitope/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/symresack/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/logicor/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/bounddisjunction/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/cumulative/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/nonlinear/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/pseudoboolean/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/superindicator/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/indicator/maxprerounds = 0
constraints/components/maxprerounds = 0
presolving/maxrestarts = 0
presolving/maxrounds = 0
```

Also when I use the set diffsave command these are all written in the file.

However after solving the model and write it with write gentransproblem I still get:

```
Minimize
 Obj: +1 x0 +3 x1 +6.24 x2 +0.1 x3
Subject to
 c0: +78.26 x1 +2.9 x3 >= +92.3
Bounds
 0.6 <= x0 <= 0.6
 0.0121390237669308 <= x1 <= 100000.45
 0.1 <= x2 <= 0.1
 18 <= x3 <= 31.5
End
```

So there is still some presolving done (rows are removed and changed to bounds)

Comment: I edited my original answer to address this problem as well